# SikuliX + python, getting weird NameError after editing of imported module

Tags: python, python-import, jython, nameerror, sikuli-x

I found a weird behavior of SikuliX + Python. My main application runs without any problems... But if i do any changes in imported module i got error

> NameError: name 'myLib' is not defined

If i restart my SikuliX program everything is okey again... It is very annoning bug.. I rlly dont know how deal with that.. I will describe my situation more detailed:

.......................................................................

I have folder with my sikulix project:

```
C:\project\
```

I have folder with main application:

```
C:\project\application.sikuli
```

I have folder with my module:
(which i am importing to main application)

```
C:\project\myLib.sikuli
```

content of my module myLib:

```
from sikuli import *

def myFunc1():
    print(" myFunc1 ")
```

content of my main application:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\project\myLib.sikuli")
from myLib import *

myFunc1()
```

.......................................................................

- If i run main application, " myFunc1 " is printed. Everything is okey without any problems.
- If i run my module myLib, nothing happens. Everything is okey without any problems.
- If i made any irrelevant changes in myLib module (for example, a new line at the end of a file) i m getting error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File '<string>', line 1, in <module>
> NameError: name 'myLib' is not defined
> [error] IDE: Run Script: internal error:
> ```

I m getting this error if i run main application and also if i try to run myLib.

- **If i restart my SikuliX everything is okey again**... New line at the end of myLib is not problem anymore.

It looks as some internal bug of SikuliX, but I am not very experienced with SikuliX so I will greatly appreciate your opinions about this behavior.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got solution of this from **RaiMan** (https://github.com/RaiMan):

> This is normal behavior, since the IDE only has a static context for
>   the Jython interpreter (not completely reset on restart of scripts in
>   the same IDE session, to save the start-up time of some seconds).
>
> There is a note in the docs in the section Some comments on general
>   rules for Python import

In your case using:

```
import myLib
from myLib import *
```

instead of only

```
from myLib import *
```

should help to trigger the reload on script rerun.